# How to convert this scriptlet into JSTL?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I've been reading up on JSTL and for the life of me I still cannot understand how some things work.  Are there any short tutorials or brief run-throughs of the essential concepts and functions of JSTL?  How do you convert this scriptlet into JSTL?  I'm using some of my own defined classes and JSTL doesn't seem to recognize them.  It gives out a "must prefix with some namespace" error when the jsp page is called.

sessionCheck.jspf

```
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.Cookie" %>
<%@ page import="sessionmanager.Errors" %>
<%@ page import="sessionmanager.SessionCheck" %>
<%@ page import="sessionmanager.SessionManager" %>
<%@ page import="sessionmanager.SessionManager.Cookies" %>
<%
String sessionId = null;
Cookie cookies[] = request.getCookies();
if(cookies != null) for(Cookie cookie : cookies)
  if(cookie.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(Cookies.SESSION_ID.getName()))
  {
    sessionId = cookie.getValue();
    break;
  }

SessionCheck sessionCheck = new SessionCheck(sessionId);
Errors error = sessionCheck.getError();
Cookie sessionIdCookie = new Cookie(Cookies.SESSION_ID.getName(), sessionId);
if(error == Errors.NONE)
{
  sessionIdCookie.setMaxAge(SessionManager.cookieMaxAge);
}
else
{
  sessionIdCookie.setMaxAge(0);
}
response.addCookie(sessionIdCookie);
%>
```

Comment: You don't, that's mostly logic you would do in a servlet.

Comment: But I need it as scriptlet.  I insert this as fragment in every jsp page to determine if request has session or not.  I have my own session management system in place.

Comment: And you replicate that to each and every page? I correct my comment: you would do that in a filter.

Comment: Filter? What is a filter? Any pointers?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try out this filter you mentioned.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info